# How to Integrate Ogone payment gateway in one page checkout in magento

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, checkout

I am trying to integrate Ogone/Ingenico payment gateway in my Magento application. The requirement has one page checkout. So i need to show the Ogone/Ingenico payment form inside the checkout page, but when i try to integrate, it redirects to Ogone/Ingenico website's payment page.

please let me know how to integrate, so that the payment form loads inside our checkout page in Magento instead of redirecting to Ogone/Ingenico website.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to activate OPC ( One Page Checkout ) feature on ogone back office.

For more information on FlexChekOut, please visit our support page at

https://payment-services.ingenico.com/int/en/ogone/support/guides/integration%20guides/flexcheckout.

**Update(from the comments)**: To enable the certain option on your test account, please go to Configuration >> Account >> Your options

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can i enable OPC. I have been searching for it in my Ingenico account but I could not able to locate the page to enable it.

Comment: To enable the certain option on your test account, please go to Configuration >> Account >> Your options

Answer (score 0):

To enable the option OPC feature on your test account, please go to Configuration >> Account >> Your options